# Django admin many to many field width

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I use [filter_vertical](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_vertical), but the problem is my models string representation is too long, it doesn't fit given `<select>` tag. Is there simple way to increase width of that select?

[image]

**Update**. One possible solution - use css to override widget styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes by using jQuery that you inject using the [Meta class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, thought seems I've found another solution - override css styles.